# Calling getwd() from within a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a Shiny app that needs to access a user's working directory. I assumed getwd() would work from within the Shiny app, however this always points to the directory of the Shiny app itself.

Example:

From the R console:

```
setwd("~/Documents")
getwd()
[1] "/Users/chris.harrison/Documents"
```

From the following Shiny app saved on the desktop:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("wd")
)

server <- function(input, output){
 output$wd <- renderText(getwd())
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And then calling:

```
setwd("~/Documents")
shiny::runApp("~/Desktop/app.R")
```

the output is:

```
/Users/chris.harrison/Desktop
```

Is there any way to call the user's working directory from within the app?

Many thanks,

Chris

Comment: You are actually calling the working directory from within the app. As your app is in Desktop, and not in Document, your automatic working directory is in Desktop. You need to set the directory inside the app (which runs its own R cession i think)

Comment: Sure, but the app is to be ported within a package. Therefore, some way of specifying the user's local working directory is needed to specify a list of user defined csvs. To complicate matters, this is to be used on R Studio server NOT on a local machine. I thought that the File Input widget might be the solution, but this always defaults to directories on the users local machine.